# getting hydration error for svg inside Link in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting an hydration error for an icon inside link,
This is the error:

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <svg> in <a>.
```

This is the code snippet:

```
               <>
               <Link  sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={loginClickHandler} >
                 <AccountCircleIcon onClick={loginClickHandler} />
               </Link> 
                <Menu
                  id="simple-menu"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  keepMounted
                  open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                  onClose={loginMenuCloseHandler}
                >
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={(e) => loginMenuCloseHandler(e, '/profile')}
                  >
                    Profile
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem
                    onClick={(e) =>
                      loginMenuCloseHandler(e, '/order-history')
                    }
                  >
                    Order History
                  </MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={logoutClickHandler}>Logout</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </>
```

Any help would be appreciated,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this type of error with NextJS. Most of the time I ignore it and my code still works fine.

But the problem I have noticed in your code is that you are using `<Link>` without the `href` attribute which is necessary, if not use `div` instead.

Do this and see if it still raises the same error.

Comment: still getting the error